# Proof of Transitivity

Tags: proof-writing

Let R be the following relation of x and y on Z where 3x + y is even.

I can seem to get to the form of $3x + z$ when I am doing algebraic manipulations if this equation. I have $3x + y = 2k$ and $3y + z = 2i$ for some $k, i \in Z$. I substituted $y$ into the second equation and tried coming up with $3x + z$ as even.

Thank for the help in advance! I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something simple here.

Comment: Hint: first show that the relation is symmetric. That will make transitivity easier.

Answer (score 0):

$3x+z = (2k-y)+(2i-3y) = 2(k+i-2y)$ which is an even number.